# how to split a variable containing a set of strings

Tags: jquery, css

I have a variable that captures an assortment of strings:

```
 var values = $('#main option').text(); // This captures every #main option value and throws it all into one long string like: one/two/three/four/five...
```

I'm trying to do an if statement saying that if someone enters text into the input field, and it doesn't match any of the string values retrieved from the variable values, then do whatever... so

```
 if($('.#main input').on('focusout', function(){
     var values = $('#main option').text();
     var inputValue = $('#main input').val();
     if(inputValue == values){
        //do something
     } 
 });
```

Not sure if its because "var inputValue" is returning value and not text or what. But since this has to be val() to pull back the string value, I can't seem to match this to the set of values returned from "var values", like: var test = values.split(','); doesn't split up the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is how you're fetching the list of valid strings. If you have an array, determining a match is trivial:

```
var $in = $('#main input'),
    dict = $('#main option').get().map(_ => _.innerHTML)

$in.on('focusout', _ => {
    if (dict.indexOf($in.val()) < 0) {
        console.log('unmatched')
    } else {
        console.log('matched')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array using `split('/')` and then compare your `enteredText` variable against all the items in the array using `indexOf`.

Whenever you run `indexOf` against an array and none of the array items match, the returned value is `-1`.

**eg.**

```
var valuesArray = values.split('/');

if (valuesArray.indexOf(enteredText) === -1) {

[... CODE HERE...]

}
```

**Working Example:**

```js
var values = 'red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet'
var valuesArray = values.split(', ');
var enteredColors = ['blue','purple'];

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

    var enteredText = enteredColors[i];

    if (valuesArray.indexOf(enteredText) === -1) {
        window.alert('Test ' + (i + 1) + ': The color ' + enteredText + ' IS NOT a color of the rainbow.');
    }

    else {
        window.alert('Test ' + (i + 1) + ': The color ' + enteredText + ' IS a color of the rainbow.');
    }

}
```

Comment: hmmm the code seems to run the function no matter what is in the (enteredText)... and I made up some jibberish string to make sure it's not in there like 'afsfesafsefs' so that I knew it wasn't in the array

Comment: It should definitely work. I've added a working example to the post above so you can see `indexOf` in action.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to create a list of all the texts first. You could also filter the options matching the text. (Chances are you want to do something with the match. This way it's already selected)

```
var text= $(this).val(),
    matches = $('#main option').filter(function(){return $(this).text() == text});
```

Example code (changed the event to keyup for the sake of testing. if 'aa', 'bb' or 'cc' is typed in the input, it should trigger a response)

```js
 $('#main input').on('keyup', function(){ //used keyup instead of focusout for easier testing
  var text= $(this).val(),
    matches = $('#main option').filter(function(){return $(this).text() == text});
  if(matches.length)  {
     console.log('Match on ' + matches.text()); //test console output
     matches.prop('selected',true); //set select to the specific option
  } 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=main>
<select>
<option>aa</option>
<option>bb</option>
<option>cc</option>
</select>
<input/>
</div>
```